# stop jQuery button event on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/29/embedded/result/

In the attached jsfiddle link above .cd-hero has 3 slides that are activated by click. I'm trying to add a stop event to the jQuery only on the third slide ("thank you") so that the user stops on that slide (doesn't slide right or go back to the previous slides). I am new to jQuery any help on how to achieve this is much appreciated!

I have tried applying the below without success:

```js
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if($(this).hasClass('.thanks')){
       event.stopPropagation();
      } else {
        var activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
        var selectedPosition =  activePosition + 1;
        nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $(''), selectedPosition);

        updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## HTML

```
<a href="" class="cd-btn" id="BtnThankyou">Thank you</a>
```

## JS

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
           if($(this)[0].id == "BtnThankyou"){

           return false;
           }

            event.preventDefault();
            var activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
            var selectedPosition =  activePosition + 1;
            nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $(''), selectedPosition);

          updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
           });
```

## [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Suganth745/z3q2wtLf/33/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a button that removes the other buttons by setting their "display" property to "none" or use $(this).hide()

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the click event from the button.

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if($(this).hasClass('.thanks')){
       $('body').unbind('click','.cd-btn'); // Unbind the click event
      } else {
        var activePosition = $('.cd-hero-slider .selected').index();
        var selectedPosition =  activePosition + 1;
        nextSlide($('.cd-hero-slider'), $(''), selectedPosition);

        updateNavigationMarker(selectedPosition + 1);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more class to the last `.cd-btn`(thank you button, for example, `.btn-thank-you`) and then use `$('.cd-btn:not(.btn-thank-you)')` to exclude it from click event.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/z3q2wtLf/32/)

Answer (score 0):

Dee i just updated your jsFiddle, adding a simple condition solution, if count of items "n" is equal to the length don't fire the events.

```
function nextSlide(container, pagination, n) {

if(n != container.children('li').length){

var visibleSlide = container.find('.selected'),
  navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');

visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
  visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
});

container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
navigationDot.removeClass('selected')
pagination.find('li').eq(n).addClass('selected');

checkVideo(visibleSlide, container, n);

}else{ //Thank You events }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z3q2wtLf/35/